# How to concatenate ReadOnlyCollection

Tags: c#, concatenation, readonly-collection

The ReadOnlyCollection constructor requires that you give it IList.
But if you have some ROC's that you want to concatenate and produce a new ROC, the Concat method returns IEnumerable.  Which is not a valid argument to pass to the ROC constructor.

So how do you create a ROC as the concatenation of other ROC's?

So far, this is the best I can come up with:

```
ReadOnlyCollection<T> ROCConcat<T> ( ReadOnlyCollection<T> a, ReadOnlyCollection<T> b)
{
    List<T> tmp = new List<T>();
    foreach (T f in a.Concat(b))
        tmp.Add(f);
    return new ReadOnlyCollection<T>(tmp);
}
```

Comment: Note that when you do this you break the link between the ROC and it's underlying `IList` so if the `IList` is modified (a item was added or removed from the list, I am not talking about items in the lists being modified) `a` and `b` would show the modification but your new concated collection would still show the original `IList`'s concated together.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you can use [ReadOnlyCollectionBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd630335%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do this.

```
return (new ReadOnlyCollectionBuilder<T>(a.Concat(b))).ToReadOnlyCollection();
```

Comment: I did not know this class even existed, kudos!

Comment: A class created specifically for this purpose.  Awesome, thank you.  :-)

Answer (score 15):

Create a new `List<>` out of your `IEnumerable<>`:

```
return new ReadOnlyCollection<T>(a.Concat(b).ToList());
```

Or I prefer:

```
return a.Concat(b).ToList().AsReadOnly();
```

These basically do the same thing as what you've come up with, but they're a little easier on the eyes.

Comment: Ahh.  So I was reinventing the ToList and AsReadOnly methods. But conceptually this is still the same. I guess creating intermediate list is not significant performance problem, so this is good enough. But if there's a way to do this without creating intermediate list, I would probably accept that other answer instead.

Comment: @EdwardNedHarvey: That's correct. The key is to realize that `ReadOnlyCollection` is simply a wrapper around an existing list. That's why it's `AsReadOnly()` instead of `ToReadOnly()`. So the List itself is not an *intermediate* step--it is the structure that the `ReadOnlyCollection` is based on. `.Concat()` is cheap, `.ToList()` is expensive, and `.AsReadOnly()` is cheap.